# last charecter on rtl goes first of the line

Tags: html, css

in my html the below string will generated by js and it will append to a p tag ... my html is RTL since the language is Persian but in some points i have englihsh characters like this.

```
#C   C#  D
```

but the above generated string is displayed like this

```
C    C#   D#
```

I tested this code but not worked for me :

```
unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
```

This is my Code :

```
<p id="chord-3" class="chord">C        C#       D#  </p>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need? Cause I really didn't understand much :)

Comment: @Synapsis post Edited

Comment: Can you show the code where you make this data print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html{
  direction:rtl
}
.ltr{
  direction:ltr;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<p class="ltr">#C   C#  D</p>
<p>مرحبا</p>
```

well add a class to this english word width css:

```
 direction:ltr;
  text-align:right;
```